# How to change aif to be able to access 'it' within the macrocall without making 'it' public in the package

Tags: common-lisp

If you put the aif code presented in [onlisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) in a package and try to use it in another you run in the problem that packagename:it is not external.

```
(in-package :packagename)

(defmacro aif (test-form then-form &optional else-form)
  ‘(let ((it ,test-form))
     (if it ,then-form ,else-form)))
```

wanted call syntax

```
(in-package :otherpackage)

(aif (do-stuff)
  (FORMAT t "~a~%" it)
  (FORMAT t "just got nil~%"))
```

How can I fix this behavior in code, without making the variable it external in the package declaration and beeing able to access `it` just by `it` instead of `packagename:it`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defmacro aif (test then &optional else)
  ;;; read-from-string will intern the symbol
  ;;; in the current package, with the correct
  ;;; read-table-case
  (let ((it (read-from-string "it")))
    `(let ((,it ,test))
       (if ,it ,then ,else))))
```

or this works too:

```
(defmacro aif (test then &optional else)
  ;;; (intern "IT") or (intern "it") will work
  ;;; as well, depending on your readtable settings.
  ;;; using string or symbol-name gets around that.
  (let ((it (intern (string 'it))))
    `(let ((,it ,test))
       (if ,it ,then ,else))))
```

Comment: it works but isn't there a more elegant way that a later reader of the macro knows what the intention of those 'weird' lines were?

Comment: which lines are the 'wierd' ones?

Comment: in my opinion the `(let ((it (read-from-string "it"))` line not self-explaining

Comment: `intern` also interns the symbol in the current package (as a default), and makes it clear that this is your intent. That's sort of what it's for.